# what's the purpose to use 'is' keyword in Typescript's type annotation

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm reading a Typescript book and saw some code like this:

```
class Product {
   ...
}

function Test(args): args is Product {
   return args instanceof Product;
}
```

But isn't that the function's return type is boolean? so we can write a normal function as:

```
function Test(args): boolean {
   return args instanceof Product;
}
```

what's the benefits to use the return type annotation as `args is XXX` instead of simple `boolean`?

Answer (score 3):

You're describing using a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

The example from the documentation illustrates how these can be useful by narrowing a union type.

```js
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
    return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}
```

Any conditional branches of your code will narrow the type to `Fish` if `swim` is defined.

```
if (isFish(pet)) {
    pet.swim(); // compiler knows that `pet` is of the `Fish` type
}
```

Comment: `return 'swim' in pet` would be better?

Comment: +1 I personally prefer [the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) but I just went with the example from the TS docs.
"If you set a property to `undefined` but do not delete it, the `in` operator returns `true` for that property."

Comment: wow, good to know

Comment: What confused me with `is` is that it's really an `as` in disguise. If `isFish` just return `true` for everything, then TS will treat anything you call `isFish` on, as a `Fish`. It's basically `(pet as Fish(if my function returned true))`. Sometimes with TS I find there's some confusion with "Are you telling me? Or am I telling you?".